# Change table name in Django

Tags: python, django

I have read that the table name in Django can be customized using [Meta Options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/). I'm wondering how the db_table option could be used to keep using the app name but modify the model name slightly without hardcoding the app name.

For example, from the Django tutorial, the app name is "polls" and the model name is "poll". Lets say I want the table to be called "polls_mypoll" instead of "polls_poll". Here is what I tried, but the outer class cannot be accessed (Poll is not defined)

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "%s_%s" % (Poll._meta.app_label, "mypoll")
```

Similarly, what if I wanted to define db_table explicitly to just be the default polls_poll? I know I could just leave off the class Meta entirely and that default name would be used, but what if I wanted to be explicit about it?

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "%s_%s" % (Poll._meta.app_label, Poll._meta.model_name)
```

This doesn't work, again because Poll is not defined inside Meta.

Comment: It's not that Poll should be declared _inside_ Meta to be accessible; it's just not been fully parsed by the time Meta is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

The exception you are getting, `Poll is not defined`, is caused by your `db_table = "%s_%s" % (Poll._meta.app_label, Poll._meta.model_name)` statement referencing the `Poll` class while it is still being constructed (not yet inserted into the global scope). If you want to use references to `Poll` in the `db_table`, consider writing your own metaclass that inherits from [ModelBase](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L54), and sets the `_meta.db_table` value properly. At that point, the `Poll` name won't be available, but the actual object will be constructed and at your hand to manipulate.

Comment: Maybe you could make db_table a @property on the Meta class to lazily generate/look up the table name (inside that derived meta class).

Comment: @XORcist, well, yeah - it could detect if the value is callable - if so, replace it with the result of `callable(class)`. Regarding the `@property`, you'd need to copy-paste the method to other models if needed as there is no way of passing the base model class (that I can think of now) to the derived Meta class at construction time.

Comment: @XORcist, also note that `_meta` gets copied what `Meta` class (_not instance_) has declared, thus `_meta` will be the `property` object, not the descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

You can always extract the `app_label` from the global namespace:

```
class Meta:
    db_table = "%s_%s" % (__package__, "mypoll")
```

This makes assumptions about where your models.py file is located relative to your application, YMMV.

An alternative would be to extract the name from **[`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=globals#globals)**:

```
# determine where app_label is
# print(globals()) 
# {'__name__': 'myapp.models', '__doc__': None, ...

app_label, *_ = globals()['__name__'].partition('.')

# or simply
app_label, *_ = __name__.partition('.')

class Meta:
    db_table = "%s_%s" % (app_label, "mypoll")
```

Your second example is incomprehensible to me.  You are trying to find the name of an object by using a hardcoded reference to that object, ie. you are using its name to try and find... its name... ?