# Changing Django/Postgres db_table name

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I followed the instruction here: [Change table name in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180696/change-table-name-in-django) to move my django models to a different app. It worked, but now my models are referencing the old table name in

```
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'api_currency'
```

What is the appropriate way to migrate the name of this table back to the default, countries_currency, as it is in the countries_currency app?

Comment: Get rid of the `class Meta: …`. then run makemigrations and migrate

Comment: @peter did you manage to find an answer to this question?

Answer (score -1):

By default django creates table name after your app_name ([Read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#table-names)).
Which is this way, so that you can have same table name in different apps.

To move back to default, first manually delete migration file created for table `api_currency`. If you already have also migrated then you can either manually delete the row in table `django_migrations` (It keeps track of all migration file that has been migrated, so just delete that row which contains the migration file name, where this table was created) in your database or by running fake migrations. (WARNING: Delete only if there is no valuable data in database.)

After that, remove this Meta option and then run make_migrations again and migrate.

Comment: Please don’t suggest deleting migrations like this. It’s only really suitable if there isn’t any important data in the database and you are happy to drop the database and recreate it. If you need to keep the existing database, then deleting migration files will mean they are out of sync, which can be very difficult to fix.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes you are right, as per question it looks like its still in creation phase (though i shouldn't have assumed) hence gave this solution. I have put up a warning to make this clear Thank you.